# React-Apollo : Passing components state to query variables

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

Is it possible to somehow inject components state into the query options?
Something like with props ?

```
options: (ownProps : any, ownState???) =>{
        console.log(a)
        return {
            variables: {
                name : ownProps.name
                id:  ownState.id <-------------------------

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question i found out that Apollo's re-fetch method which according to documentation

`The variables argument will replace variables used with either the query option or the query from your graphql()`

This solves the issue.